# Refresh token denied and empty response for viewing tokens in token store

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have deployed an azure app to azure app service. It has no frontend part, simply an API app that does some http calls.

I have configured the Authentication/Authorization section to log anonymous requests using Azure AD.

I have registered the app in AD and connected everything together.

Here is the problem:

1. Upon first sign in, everything works great, I sign in and the jwt token is sent to my app and I can parse it.
2. However if I am already signed in and go to my app again a jwt token is not sent. However doing a GET request to `/.auth/me` simply returns `[]`.
3. If I send a request to `/.auth/refresh` I get a `403 forbidden`.

A bit stuck on how to proceed here. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the status of your `Action to take when request is not authenticated`? Is it `Allow anonymous` or `Sign-in with Azure AD`?

If it is the former (allow anonymous), what you observe is expected behavior.

If it the latter - it is not expected.

When you set to "Allow anonymous" you instruct to not do anything if request is not authenticated. So, nothing happens, and you do not see any token. If you configure to "Login with ...", you will be automatically redirected if you are not authenticated.

**UPDATE**

Can you define "If I am already signed in.."? Also, if you configured to **not** allow anonymous request, every request hitting your application code will be authenticated. The app service authentication module takes care of intercepting unauthenticated calls and redirects them. Additionally `/.auth/me` endpoint will redirect to sign-in all unauthenticated calls, but `/.auth/refresh` will not.

You may also want to enable token store, which is enabled by default. The option is located directly under the list with authentication providers.

You can find more information about authentication and authorization in Azure App Service here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to - check out the sections `access user claims`, `retrieve tokens in app code` and `refresh identity provider token`

Comment: The login works. I have disabled anonymous access and instead use Azure ad and configured accordingly. I can login. However the request to refresh the token or to get the user token from token store returns empty.

Comment: Essentially what I want is to verify the user if that user is already logged in. If they are logged in I do t get a jwt token from azure so will need to get the id token which is when I encountered this issue.